# Umbraco Navigation Service on ng-table's ng-click event

Tags: angularjs, umbraco7

I am trying to navigate the control on ng-click to a view of a custom section.
this is the ng-click on td.

```
<td data-title="'Name'" sortable="'Name'" filter="{ 'Name': 'text' }" class="date" ng-click="openDetail(item)" > {{ item.Name}}
```

this is my js file

```
$scope.openDetail = function (Item) {


    }
```

i was playing with navigation services but didnt find anything there :(

Is there any service available for doing it in umbraco?where we can specify the path and querystring parameters.

Thanks,

Comment: Could you explain a bit more in detail what are you trying to achieve in order to help you, please? I assume you already had a look at http://umbraco.github.io/Belle/#/api/umbraco.services.navigationService